# I manually uninstalled my app from AVD, do I have to install it again manually?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I uninstalled my app because it was not updating with the code I was doing in Android Studio hoping that it would be installed again when I'll restart the emulator. But now my app is not showing in menu of emulator. What to do? do I have to install the app again manually?
**here's what I've already tried**

- cold boot the emulator

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to see if it works with another blank project.
2. If 1 doesn't work, reinstall the emulator.

If it still doesn't work,... save the whole project into a place you know safe, and try to reinstall Android Studio...